# Is there a way to pull data from a txt file and make it update everytime the txt file is updated?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to pull data from a txt file and make it update everytime the txt file is updated? I'm using the following code in my program and it will find the file and display its content fine but when I update the txt file, the program does not update the new text.

```
function OnFileLoad() 
{
    var file = document.getElementById("FileReader").files[0];
     
    var fileDisplayArea = document.getElementById("FileContent");
    if (file.type.match('text.*|image.*|application.*')) 
    {
        console.log('hello. we are inside the function')
        var reader = new FileReader();
          
        reader.onload = function (e) 
        {
          fileDisplayArea.innerText = reader.result;
        }

        reader.readAsText(file);
    } 
    else 
    {
        fileDisplayArea.innerText = "File not supported!"
    }
}
```

Comment: Plain vanilla JS does not have the ability to alter local files.  You can read a text file as you have found, but you cannot write it back, with or without changes.  Could could copy an altered copy of the original, but you will need a wordprocessor to save your changes manually or a server program to do it remotely.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that its the script of an HTML. There is input for a file with id = FileReader.